# Sticky Header in Chrome iOS App doesn't animate until Scrolling is stopped

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, sticky

Is there a way to get the animation for the sticky header to fire upon page scroll rather than waiting for the page to stop scrolling?  In Chrome's iOS app the sticky header doesn't stick for me until the page has stopped scrolling. in Safari, it happens right away which is what i'd like it to do:

http://sdchamber.org

```
// Sticky Header - Home
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
        $('#header-home').addClass("sticky");
    }
    else{
        $('#header-home').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

And here's my css

```
.header-home {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.header-home.sticky { 
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 130px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 15px 0px 10px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to fix this for years. Not a surprize that noone answered. Have tried different combination with fixed, absolute (+top=scrollTop), without transition, nothing works. There is that stupid delay.